# MySQL audit and general log

Tags: mysql, database-recommendation, audit, logs

May ask for the difference of MySQL Audit log plugin and general log? I looking for any activities done in a MySQL server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Audit Plugin

MySQL Enterprise Audit is a new feature for **security and compliance**. It's not included in the Open Source / Community edition.

> As of MySQL 5.6.10, MySQL Enterprise Edition includes MySQL Enterprise
>   Audit, implemented using a server plugin named audit_log. MySQL
>   Enterprise Audit uses the open MySQL Audit API to enable standard,
>   policy-based monitoring and logging of connection and query activity
>   executed on specific MySQL servers. Designed to meet the Oracle audit
>   specification, MySQL Enterprise Audit provides an out of box, easy to
>   use auditing and compliance solution for applications that are
>   governed by both internal and external regulatory guidelines.

have a look at [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/audit-log.html) for more details.

By the way, MariaDB has its own implementation [Audit Plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-the-mariadb-audit-plugin/). You can specify what exactly you wish to log.

- CONNECT
- QUERY
- QUERY_DDL
- QUERY_DML
- QUERY_DCL

### General Query Log

The general log is a quite old feature for the DBA and developer **(to troubleshoot issues)**. The general log has a big performance impact and should be only enabled during short time slots.

> The general query log is a general record of what mysqld is doing. The
>   server writes information to this log when clients connect or
>   disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients. The
>   general query log can be very useful when you suspect an error in a
>   client and want to know exactly what the client sent to mysqld.

more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html).

Comment: Thank you for the simple but informative comparison of two.